# How do I get Overachiever Level 2?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

In the latest edition of Sunset Overdrive on PC, you start with the Overachiever Weapon Amp at Level 1, and [the Wiki](https://sunsetoverdrive.fandom.com/wiki/Amps#Weapon) indicates that there's a second level of it like most other Amps.

Chaos Squad doesn't exist anymore on PC, and all of its stuff appear to be just sold for OverCharge. But I've completed the main game, with just the Flag swapping quests and "Mooil Rig" as missions / DLC left, and a lot of Challenges undone.

I checked again and am quite sure I can't buy Overachiever Level 2 at Floyd's, is there some condition to unlock it that I haven't hit yet, or was it removed in the latest edition?